# Sorting models after joining the relational table when both tables have same column names

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building an application on `Laravel`, where I'm having `Project` and `LatestStatus` model, I've a table which has sorting facilities. So I can sort by name, its latest-status, last updated by etc. So the architecture of this is:

```
projects
    id
    name -> string
    state -> string
    region -> string
    status -> enum ('saved', 'draft')
    created_at -> timestamp
    updated_at -> timestamp

project_latest_status
    id
    project_id -> integer   // (project id foreign key)
    status -> string       //  (current status of project)
```

I want to sort projects by joining the `latest_status` table and sort according to current status of project. For this I tried something like this:

```
Project::where('status', 'saved')
    ->when( $request->name , function( $q) use( $request ) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name .'%');
    }) 
    ->when($request->status, function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->whereHas('latestStatus', function ($q) use($request){
            $q->whereHas('status', function ($q) use($request) {
                $q->whereIn('name',  collect($request->status)->pluck('name') );
            });
        });
    })
    ->when($request->sort_by_column, function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->when($request->sort_by_column['column'] == 'name' || $request->sort_by_column['column'] == 'website', function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->orderBy($request->sort_by_column['column'], $request->sort_by_column['order'] );
        })
        ->when($request->sort_by_column['column'] == 'added_date' , function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->orderBy('created_at', $request->sort_by_column['order']);
        })
        ->when($request->sort_by_column['column'] == 'status', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->join('project_latest_status', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_latest_status.project_id')
                ->join('project_status', 'project_latest_status.status', '=', 'project_status.id')
                ->select('projects.*', 'project_status.name as status_name')
                ->orderBy('status_name', $request->sort_by_column['order']);
        })
    })->get();
```

Everything works fine but as soon as I click on status sort it gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `projects` inner join `project_latest_status` on `projects`.`id` = `project_latest_status`.`project_id` inner join `project_status` on `project_latest_status`.`status` = `project_status`.`id` where `status` = saved and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null)"

Help me out in this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change where from

```
where('status', 'saved')
```

to

```
where('projects.status', 'saved')
```

or where ever you use `status` with another join table another same field so you need to specify the table where you want to filter by `status`